# Best way to handle large PHP page loading with Jquery/Ajax/HTML etc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Happy New Year, Hope you are well.

I am working on a project which generates a "league table" based on a lot of data, similar to the ones used in various sports (namely football). I have built the backend in PHP which processes the data and outputs the results, however it can take about 6-9 seconds per user, with an average of 10-20 users in a group the page load would take over a minute. To be honest, I expected it to take longer than that as the script has to loop through about 10,000 records per user and do quite a bit of arithmetic.

My question is, what is the best way to load this data into a page? The way I had done it was by having a div the size of the page, on top of all other content, which simply said loading in the middle - this would then make it's self hidden once the page had loaded. This approach was fine but i think it is leaving the door open for various issues - one could be the page timing out or the user thinks it has crashed etc.

What I have been advised to do is have a lightweight page, that calls a api on the server to initiate the request. The api responds with a request id (or something to identify the request anyway), then starts to generate the data. The page would query the api every say 15 seconds to see how its doing, eventually the api would respond saying its complete - then the user would be redirected to view the report.

Any advise/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Smithey.

Comment: How often does this information change? Could you look at caching?

Comment: Do you have to load the whole page at ones? i mean if your working with a table you can paginate your data or load it only when needed

Comment: It could also be possible to use a better SQL query to fetch the data and handle some of the heavy lifting. If you have to loop through tens of thousands of records per user when generating the page, it sounds a bit weird, unless you're actually also displaying 10 000 records.

Comment: The data that is used to generate the report would never change as such. However "new" data is added about once per minute, which could have an impact on the end result. Could you cache that?

Comment: @JaniHartikainen The data comes from a rest api (on another server), it is stored in MySQL at that end but thats about all I know - its hosted by a 3rd party so my access is limited :(. Getting the initial data only takes a few milliseconds so i don't think that is the issue

Comment: @NetaMeta Ideally, yes it would be whole table - it would be about 10-20 rows in total...

Comment: Without seeing code, it's hard to say, but I'd venture a guess that your code is not processing using the optimal method.  But, this is about the client code, not the server.  If it were me, I'd setup an AJAX call as you suggested, then using either WebSockets or long polling to get notified when the processing was done.  There are a few libraries that spring to mind, Atmosphere was one I used a while back, but I am sure there are thousands of them out there.  You could even set things up so the data changes real-time.

Comment: will the data displayed be different between each user ? if not - you said that about every 1 minute you have new entry. if you are capable of telling the difference between old data to new data, you can make a cron job that will check for that difference every 10-30 minutes and update that. or use some data push tools

Comment: @Smithey93 okay sounds like it might be worthwhile to look into having some kind of process that handles the calculation behind the scenes and puts the final results into a DB you can query directly with better speed. Although if the user doesn't need to reload the page a lot, 5-6 seconds load time might be tolerable (just make sure to inform the user)

Comment: @CodeChimp I'll have a look into that, what i was planning to do is use ajax polling then I can update what it says on the page every time it polls the server. For example "Processed x Events", or something like that so the user knows that something is happening. I thought about web sockets, but unfortunately I have to support IE8/9+ - this in its self is a nightmare...

Comment: I know that Atmosphere did WebSockets, but gracefully degraded when used in older browsers.  Might take some of the heavy lifting off of you.

Comment: @NetaMeta The data is different for each user within a group. What i had thought about is having a process that runs every hour, that updates a database at my end containing the totals (these are what are actually displayed in the page). The problem here is the end-user may want to view the report/page based on all data within a month, a week, a day although 90% of the time it will be the past month.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to load the data into a `div` in the page, example code (this code uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)) :

HTML :

```
<div id="loading"><p>Please wait, loading data...</p></div>
<div id="data"></div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(function(){ // This is so that it executes only once the document is loaded
    $("#data").load("/script.php", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if(status == "success") {
            // On success
            $('#loading').hide(); // Hides the "please wait" text
        } else if (status == "error") {
            // Do something on error
            alert("Could not load data, please refresh the page."); // Example alert
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @SalmanA your page is just a plain HTML page with no PHP code and gets served instantly; and then that page loads the data from the PHP script; that way your website loads instantly and it also tells your visitors if something is wrong when loading the data (on my example it just displays an alert box).

Comment: Oops - I missed this, sorry! This approach would work, better than what I'm doing now (one "big" page hidden by a div). However, what i want to do is update the end-user on where the servers at processing the code. Silly as it sounds, the end-user would end up thinking "it isn't working" because they have seen the same message saying loading for ~10 seconds... Telling them to wait isn't an option, I've tried that in the past lol.

Comment: @Smithey93 maybe put a dummy progress bar with the average loading time set on it ? That way users will have the feeling that it's working... but the best option would be to cache the information server-side (for example, a cron job that runs every 5 minutes and puts fresh data into the cache) and the page would just instantly get and display the cached data.